# ajax send data to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm was wondering what is the difference between these two syntaxes:

```
  var value = $("#myForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: value
});
```

and

```
  var value = $("#myForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: "valueName=" + value
});
```

I thought they are the same but when I use the first one, in my spring controller this attribute have fully populated properties. When I use the second approach, all the properties of the attribute are null ??

Someone have explanation for this?

This is my **JSP**:

```
<form:form id="myForm" action="*" modelAttribute="filters" >

    <form:input ...  path="age" />  
    <form:input ...  path="gender" />   
    <form:input ...  path="location" /> 

</form:form>
```

This is JS

```
$('#ok_provinces_btn_id').click(function(){
var second = $('#secondAttr').val();

var f = $("#myForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: ?????
});
```

});

This is my **Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="testMethod", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void testMethod(
        @ModelAttribute("filters") FiltersWrapper filters,
                    @RquestParam String second
        ){

             //Here the **second** param is OK 
    filters.getAge(); //NULL
}
```

Comment: The latter one has `valueName=` before the serialized string

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Try `console.log(f); // or alert(f);` after you serialized form and copy past result there. Also, what shows `network` tab on firebug (do you use it or same utility?) after you call this controller.

Comment: When I try 'alert(f)' it prints me: 'state=VA&age=20&gender=f'. I don't use firebug or some other utility

Comment: It is valid query. So whats the problem? You have to use 1st variant (your code). I explained why you get null attributes. What is your question now?

Comment: I have few other places in my code where I use this approach that U suggest. The problem here is that I need to send to my controller not only this form but one extra parameter. How can I do this ?

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to send form parameters + one extra. Why you can't put extra parameter to your form as `<input type='hidden' ... >`? Anyway, I answered to this question in my answer edit.

Comment: I will try this idea. It looks promising. Thank you! I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @user2883938 Also, it is a good practise to use utilities like firebug. You can use firebug in FireFox, CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome (console) or OpenOpera Dragonfly in Opera. You can track different actions by this tools (like ajax requests, or console logs (its is `alert` function analog but for console) etc...)

Comment: That's really good idea. I will try this utilities. I'm not very  experienced web developer. So far I use alert for everything but its real pain to debug like this. THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explaining why you get null attributes with your code** In your first variant (**it is correct and will work**):

```
  var value = $("#myForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: value
});
```

You already had serialized form into `value` variable.

In the second variant (**it is incorrect and wouldn't work**):

```
  var value = $("#myForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: "valueName=" + value
});
```

You serialized form data into `value` and after that added `valueName=` before serialized query. It is not correct approach at all.

Query string must be such, for example: `param1=bob&param2=bob1&param3=mama`. But in your 2nd example query string is: `valueName=param1=bob&param2=bob1&param3=mama`. It is invalid query. Thats why properties are null.

**Sending data without serializing form** If you want to send some parameters, you have to use another approach (anyway params are form or non-form):

```
var param1 = $("#id_of_needed_data").val();
var param2 = $("#id_of_needed_data").val();
// etc
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2; // etc
});
```

**Sending form data + some extra params** Firstyly, I don't think it is good idea to send form fields + some extra. I think better is to add this extra params to your form as hidden fields. Anyway, if you want to send some non-in-form + in-form parameters try next code:

```
var param1 = $("#id_of_needed_data").val();
var param2 = $("#id_of_needed_data").val();
// etc
var value = $("#myform").serialize();
var query = value;
if (value != '') {
    query = query + "&";
}
query = query + "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testMethod",
    data: ; query;
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand but how can I send more then one parameters to my controller than. I try this approach but no luck: url: "testMethod?parame1=" + val1 + "&parame2=" + val2 + "&valueName=" + value. I get the first two variables correct but the value is with null parameters

Comment: Edit your answer and show full code, where you get `parame1` and `parame2`. You use right approach there. Is value getting data this way: `var value = $("#myForm").serialize();`?

Comment: `type:"POST"` & whole form is serialized, why it is still needed two  variable separately?

Comment: Yes but I don't have this parameters. I use model attribute in one form and populate all its fields by using <form:input ... path="nameOfTheParameter" ...>

Comment: Firstly, use code tags, when you write code. What you try to achieve? How final html code looks? You have to add name parameters to inputs. I don't know exactly how you can do this in your framework, it wasn't your question, but finally html code must be with `name` attributes so form can be serialized and data can be send.