# Razor view send dropdown value with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to send value of my dropdownlist

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selection, Model.liste_selection, new {@id="Selection", @class = "form-control" })
```

with this ajax post

```
<script>
$('#valider').on("click",function () {


    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Executer", "Requete")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: $('#Selection').val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```

But the value of my dropdown list doenst reach controller it goes null

Here is my controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Executer(RequeteOptimise ro, string Command)
    {

        Session["dateDebutReq"] = ro.begin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Session["dateFinReq"] = ro.end.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (ro.selection.Contains("Tous"))
        {
            var viewModel = new RequeteOptimise
            {
                nombre = rr.callReqCount(ro)
            };

            return PartialView("../utilities/Nombre", viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the declaration of your controller where you post to?

Comment: You are not referencing the key `id` in your controller.

Comment: That was it !, can please tell me how to send the whole model to controller instead of one value ?

Comment: what does your model contain???

Comment: many string fields and two dateTime fields

Comment: If the model in the view is `RequeteOptimise`, then you can use `data: $('form').serialize(),` to send all form controls in the post and bind to parameter `ro`

Comment: well sir, i'm posting this as a new question

Comment: Glad to read that you found a good answer...please stop using `Session` in MVC please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making some changes in your ajax as below

```
$('#valider').on("click",function () {
    var info={
              id:$('#Selection option:selected').text();
             };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Executer", "Requete")',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```

**Let me know if you face any problem?**

**EDIT** - Assuming that your model contains 2 strings and 2 dateTime fields I will edit the Jsondata as below:

```
 $('#valider').on("click",function () {
var date1=$('#date1ID').val();
var date2=$('#date2ID').val();
var model={
             string1: $('#string1ID').val(), 
             string2: $('#string2ID').val(),
             date1: new Date(date1),
             date2: new Date(date2)
          };

$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Executer", "Requete")',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
            }
        });
});
```

**EDIT:** `$('#string1ID').val()` - here `string1ID` is ID of whatever control from where you are fetching the value. Same incase of `string2ID`, `date1ID` and `date2ID`

**Just check if you are receiving any values in you model parameter of controller method**

**EDIT 2**- Well if you want to pass model value one by one that the above said way will work for sure but if you want to pass the whole form to the controller through Ajax you can modify it as below:

```
$('#valider').on("click",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form=$("#formID");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Executer", "Requete")',
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

For more detail on serializing the form I suggest you to go through **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036483/ajax-send-data-to-controller)**

Comment: Is  there a way to send the whole model , in the above comment they suggested using data:$('form').serialize(), because i have a lot of fields

Comment: Anytime buddy. Happy coding.. :)